# AngularFire2 4 Token only by the second call

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have a Angular4 Project and implement Auth with AngularFire2 4 !

in my Login Form i have a Button who calls the login Function:

```
login() {
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.model.email, 
this.model.password).then(
    (success) => {
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
      //console.log(token);
localStorage.setItem("JwtToken", token);
})
    }).catch(
    (err) => {
        //this.error = err;
    });
       this.dataService.gettestToken();
}




//this is the Function in the Dataservice 
public gettestToken(){
console.log(localStorage.getItem('JwtToken'));
}
```

after Login I write the IdToken in the localStorage to use them later
to access to ASP.NET WebAPI Data....

my Problem now is:
I can write the correct IDToken in the localStorage
but when i call the Function getTestToken in the Dataservice
for testing with console.log i become no Token Back... only null.

but the crazy Thing is when i click a second one to the Login Button
then i become the Token back!

i must click always 2 Times the Login Button to become my Token back...

but when i lock in the Developer Tools under Local Storage is the Token
written by the first click of the Login Button....

has someone an Idea where is my Problem or is this some Bug?

Comment: You are making an async call and your **this.dataService.gettestToken();** is outside the callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `this.dataService.gettestToken();` outside of two async functions.

`gettestToken()` is returning null because `signInWithEmailAndPassword` hasn't returned a promise and neither has `getIdToken()`.

You need to move `this.dataService.gettestToken()` into then `.then()` from `getIdToken()` like this:

```
login(__this = this) {
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.model.email, 
    this.model.password).then((success) => {
      this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
        //console.log(token);
        localStorage.setItem("JwtToken", token);
        // MOVE FUNCTION HERE ******************
        __this.dataService.gettestToken(); // <--------
      })
    }).catch((err) => {
    //this.error = err;
    });
}




//this is the Function in the Dataservice 
public gettestToken(){
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('JwtToken'));
}
```

EDIT:
Notice I had to add a parameter to the `login()` function: `__this = this`. This is because when `this` is inside of the promise return `this` is not referring to the class.

Comment: when i do this i become a Error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataService' of undefined